# How to use slider to adjust font size and spacing of grade letters

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I'm writing a Java code to display the grades that students in a class have achieved. I have a small problem. I want to use TWO sliders, one to adjust the text (the output) font size, and another slider to adjust the spacing between the letters. For example, when I enter the number '5' into the the JLabel box labelled #of Grade As, and I press the button the button "Display output as a string of letters", I get the result : "Grade As : AAAAA." What I would like to do (as mentioned above) is to adjust the size of the letter A, and also adjust the spacing between the consecutive letter As. Can someone please tell me how to do this. I know of course that I have to set up a JSlider, but what exactly do I do then? My partial code is the following :

```
          if ( e.getSource() == displayChartButton ) {

          checkAndRecordData();

          Graphics g = chartPanel.getGraphics();

          g.setColor(Color.white);
          g.fillRect(20,20,410,52);
          g.setColor(Color.black);
          g.drawRect(20,20,410,52);
          g.setColor( Color.black );
          g.drawString( "Grade As: " + gradeAs, chartLeftXA, chartTopYA );

      }

          if (e.getSource() == displayLongString) {

          Graphics g = chartPanel.getGraphics(); 

          g.setColor(Color.white);
          g.fillRect(20,20,410,52);
          g.setColor(Color.black);
          g.drawRect(20,20,410,52);
          g.setColor( Color.black );
          g.drawString( "Grade As: " + longStringA, 100, 50 );

       }

          private void checkAndRecordData() {

          gradeAs = tempAs;

          longStringA = "";
          String gradeLetterA = "A";
          for (int i=0; i<tempAs; i++) 
          longStringA += gradeLetterA;
       }


          public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
          int size = slider.getValue();

       }
```

Once I get to the last line, int size = slider.getValue(), I don't know what to do. Remember, I have TWO things to do. One is to adjust the size of the letters, the other is to adjust the spacing between the letters, hence I need two sliders. Can someone please help?

Comment: Instead of drawing on a `Graphics` object directly, it might be better to just add the letters as `JLabel`s with spacer objects in between - then you can call `setFont` on the `JLabel`s to set the height, and adjust the size of the spacer object, in your `stateChanged` method.

Comment: That's something I wouldn't have thought of. It's pretty clever. Much obliged !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily via recursion for child components

```
  public static void changeFont(Component component, int fontSize) {
        Font f = component.getFont();
        component.setFont(new Font(f.getName(), f.getStyle(), f.getSize() + fontSize));
        if (component instanceof Container) {
            for (Component child : ((Container) component).getComponents()) {
                changeFont(child, fontSize);
            }
        }
    }
```

you can even set you own font or font size for a child component 
by getting the name of the component

```
public static void changeFont(Component component, int fontSize) {
        Font f = component.getFont();
        component.setFont(new Font(f.getName(), f.getStyle(), f.getSize() + fontSize));
        if (component instanceof Container) {
            for (Component child : ((Container) component).getComponents()) {
                if(child.getName().equals("myComponentName")){
                //set font to the component
                }else{
                changeFont(child, fontSize);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and call this method from an event , like here i am posting how it will change the font size with the change in the value of the slider
where sldValue is my global variable to store the old slider value

```
if (!((JSlider) evt.getSource()).getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            changeFont(this, sldFontSet.getValue() - sldValue);
            sldValue = sldFontSet.getValue();
        }
```

Sorry about Spacing I am working on it

Comment: Hello Deepak, thanks for the subroutine. I'm not very familiar with recursion for child components, I will have to look it up in my Java book. In the meantime, I'll copy and paste your subroutine into my programme and see what it does. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello Deepak, Your subroutine does work and I'm getting the results I need. Thanks, mate !